# Creating a google map that shows locations that are stored in a mySQL database on Apache

Tags: mysql, apache, google-maps

I would like to create a program that shows locations that are stored in a  mysql database on a Google Map. These locations are specified in terms of latitude and longitude. Any suggestions? They would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Could anybody refer me to a resource that will teach me how to program with Google maps? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can write the objects to a KML file from your laditude and longitude and feed that directly into the map. [Here](http://code.google.com/apis/kml/documentation/mapsSupport.html)'s how.

EDIT: which language will you be writing your website in? From the MySQL DB I'm guessing you are going to be using PHP. If so, [here](http://code.google.com/apis/kml/articles/phpmysqlkml.html) is how to create a KML file.

Answer (score 0):

There's a good example [here](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/articles/phpsqlajax_v3.html). It involves creating XML from MySQL data and using it as a source.

Answer (score 0):

[Documentation](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/basics.html)

you will find in there an example that uses a server on PHP with a mySQL database.

there's also a Flex version.

Answer (score 0):

From the example gallery [simple marker example](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/marker-simple.html):

```
var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-25.363882,131.044922);

//...    

var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: myLatlng, 
    map: map,
    title:"Hello World!"
});
```

Extrapolating this to a list of locations with lat, long, and description is relatively easy:

```
var locations = [/*location objects 
                   {lat: -25.123, lng: 131.123, desc: "test" }
                  ... */
var i = 0, maxLoc = locations.length;
for(i=0; i < maxLoc; i++) {
     var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i].lat,locations[i].lng);

     //...    

     var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: myLatlng, 
        map: map,
        title:locations[i].desc
    });
}
```

Comment: @j-ball - Thanks jball, which language is this?

Comment: @Engprof, this is JavaScript. I'm assuming that you're creating a web page to display the google map?

Comment: @jball- yes, but I have never programmed with JaveScript before...I'm new to this sort of thing..

Comment: @Engprof, if you click "view source" on the example I linked to, you'll see essentially all the js you need. It looks like you'll need to decide on a server side language to generate the web page, including the js for the google map. Being mostly a .Net framework programmer, I can't give you any specific recommendations for the Apache/mySQL stack you've got so far, but Perl, PHP, or Python are the traditional choices.